# Unity IOS Build weird BoringSSL error

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, unity-game-engine

I made a simple game with Unity and get built for IOS. When I try to build this app by XCode and run on my usb connected device, I see only unity logo and when app goes to first screen, it shows black screen and stucks there. In XCode log window, It says :

> 2018-05-25 02:35:46.906244+0300 helloworld[7424:2571959] [BoringSSL]
>   Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871
>   [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed
>   because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

Weird is that I never use internet connection in the app. Can anyone help to solve this problem?